# What would be the image under $R$- linear map???

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I know it's quite easy question. But I am stuck here and facing difficulty in how to figure out the answer.

Suppose $M$ is an $R$-module, where $R$ is any ring and let $N$ be its submodule.
Now for $x \in M$, Consider the $R$-linear map

> $$ \phi: R \to \frac{M}{N}$$   defined by 
>       $$\phi(r) =rx + N  $$

My question is what would be the image of $R$ under $\phi$?

Hint: Answer is given that $\phi(R)=\dfrac{Rx + N}{N}$

When we try to prove it we may do this easily by the inclusion method.
But I want to know the approach without knowing the answer.

Can we use the fact that image of $R$ will be a submodule of $\frac{M}{N}$ or what will be the way to approach the answer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $\phi(R)=R\hat x$, where $\hat x$ is the residue class of $x$ modulo $N$. (Actually $\phi$ is defined by $\phi(r)=r\hat x$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it’s easier if you split up the problem into two parts.

Consider the canonical projection $\pi\colon M\to M/N$. If $L$ is a submodule of $M$, then $\pi(L)=(L+N)/N$.

Indeed, if $z+N\in\pi(L)$, then $z+N=y+N$, for some $y\in L$, so $z-y\in N$ and so
$$
z+N=(y+(z-y))+N\in (L+N)/N
$$
Therefore $\pi(L)\subseteq(L+N)/N$.

Conversely, if $y\in L$ and $z\in N$, then
$$
(y+z)+N=\pi(y)\in\pi(L)
$$
Therefore $(L+N)/N\subseteq\pi(L)$.

In your case, $L=\psi(R)$, where $\psi\colon R\to M$ is defined by $\psi(r)=rx$. Note that $\phi=\pi\circ\psi$, so $\psi(R)=Rx$ and
$$
\phi(R)=(\pi\circ\psi)(R)=\pi(\psi(R))=\pi(Rx)=(Rx+N)/N
$$